# Post Request in VB.NET doesn't work properly

Tags: json, vb.net, post, cookies, httpwebrequest

I want to execute this request with cookies that I have saved in file(cookies are good because i can execute other requests to page)

```
http://www.banggood.com/index.php?com=event&t=recordSignInShare&fb_id=197203087314503_251208398580638&code=
```

Yes, last parameter should be empty.
When I open it in browser it gives me json data (no matter how they look)
but when i try to do the same request on vb.net app it redirects me to another page.
Here is code from VB:

```
 Dim postData As String = "com=event&t=recordSignInShare&fb_id=197203087314503_251208398580638&code="
    Dim bytes() As Byte = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
    Dim postReq As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.banggood.com/index.php")
    postReq.Method = "POST"
    postReq.KeepAlive = True
    postReq.CookieContainer = cookies
    'postReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
    postReq.Referer = "http://www.banggood.com/"
    postReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
    postReq.ContentLength = bytes.Length
    Dim postStream As Stream = postReq.GetRequestStream()
    postStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
    postStream.Close()
    Dim postResponse As HttpWebResponse
    postResponse = postReq.GetResponse()
    cookies.Add(postResponse.Cookies)
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(postResponse.GetResponseStream())
    Dim strSource As String = reader.ReadToEnd
    Return strSource
```

And it returns me html code, not json data :(

This is how looks request from network monitor when i open it by browser
Request:

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Host:www.banggood.com
Referer:http://www.banggood.com/2016midyear.html?utmid=796
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Response:
    Cache-Control:max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
    Connection:keep-alive
    Content-Length:94
    Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
I think that original(from code) request/response headers aren't important because I can execute it proper just by opening this link in browser.

Comment: When you copy/paste that url in the browser, it does a GET not a POST.

Comment: i know but other requests which were get, i used post and they worked. i will check your idea

Comment: When you'll try it, make sure you send the information as a querystring (part of the url).

Answer (score 0):

Problem was, that i need get request :P
Thanks [the_lotus](http://com=event&t=recordSignInShare&fb_id=197203087314503_251208398580638&code=)

Answer (score 0):

```
                Dim urlphp As String = "" & dominio & "" & carpetanoti & "/demanda_alta.php"
                Dim Conexion As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(urlphp), HttpWebRequest)
                Conexion.Method = "POST"
                Conexion.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                Dim POST_DATA As String = ("&cTitulo=" & "Te necesitamos!!" & "&cMensaje=" & "ALTA DEMANDA TENEMOS DOMICILIOS PARA TI" & "")
                Dim byteArray() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(POST_DATA)
                Conexion.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
                Dim FLUJO As Stream = Conexion.GetRequestStream()
                FLUJO.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
                FLUJO.Close()
                Dim Response As HttpWebResponse = Conexion.GetResponse()
                FLUJO = Response.GetResponseStream()
                Dim LEER As New StreamReader(FLUJO)
                Dim ServerResponse As String = LEER.ReadToEnd()
                LEER.Close()
                FLUJO.Close()
                Response.Close()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).